# Read input file solving task in codeeval

Tags: python

I code with python 3.4
and  try to solve some task in CodeEval. 
The input file consists of lines like:

```
31415;HYEMYDUMPS
45162;M%muxi%dncpqftiix"
14586214;Uix!&kotvx3
```

I try to read the inputfile with such way:

```
import sys

ABC = " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

test_cases = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for test in test_cases:
    cod = test.split(';')[0]
    phrase = test.split(';')[1]
def decode(cod, phrase):
    """my code"""

def main():
    decode(cod, phrase)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is it the right way to read the inputfile?
Because my solutions' status is "Partially" solved...

What is the right way to read such lines? ( i mean separated with ';' or ' ')
Tnx, Friends!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your 'phrase' may contain semi-colons too. When you split you test case line, it might be happening that it breaks your phrase containing semi-colons too into two or more parts. As you are only assigning the first part of these multiple parts to your phrase variable, hence you will get incorrect decoding in such situations.

You, will get 'Partially' solved result as the cases where the phrases do not contain semi-colons will work just fine.

I will like to point out, that this is just my guess. Please provide the text/link of the problem, so that I can take a look and be of better help.

Comment: So, here is a link to [task](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/181/) and my [solution](http://pastebin.com/V0rizFjx)